# Make HTML element based off of document width

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm trying to add a button for a mobile menu when the document width is less then 470.

It does it when the page loads initially, but when I mess with the width of the actual document on my browser it does not change alongside the document. How do I achieve this?

Button should appear when width is less then 470 and go away when page width is greater then 470, basically.

Here is my code.

```
        var width = $(document).width();
        if (width < 470) {
            $("<button id='menu'>Menu</button>").insertAfter("#navigation a img");
        } else {
            $("<button id='menu'></button>").hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check width of document every time window size change.

```
function onresize(){
   var width = $(document).width();
   if (width < 470) {
        if($("#menu").length){
               $("#menu").show();
         }
         else{
                $("<button id='menu'>Menu</button>").insertAfter("#navigation a img");
         }
    } else {
        $("#menu").hide();
    }
}

onresize()//first call
$(window).resize(onresize);
```

Comment: If I resize the browser window, it keeps creating the same button element every time its resized repeatedly. Both answers work here.

Comment: I made the change to prevent recreation of button.

Comment: @Shusl `$('#menu').length !== 0` is a redundant check. Here, you just need to say `if($('#menu').length)`

Answer (score 3):

Bind the function/checks to a `resize` method on the window:

```
$(window).resize(
    function(){
        /* do stuff in here */
    });
```

[Simple proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DL93h/).

Comment: If I resize the browser window, it keeps creating the same button element every time its resized repeatedly.

Comment: Well, yeah; because that's what your logic tells it to do. Simply check that the element `$('button#menu')` doesn't already exist before you (re)create it.